# Android Library manifest: how much needs to be duplicated?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a library project that exports several activities, requires and declares several permissions.

Docs say that imported objects from this library should be redeclared in the application `Manifest`, but how much of this information do I have to clone?

For example, where to the items in the following list go? Library manifest, app, or both?

- `<uses-permission>`
- `<uses-feature>`
- `<permission>` (creation, not requirement)
- `<activity>`
- `<activity>` attributes (`name`, `launchMode`, `screenOrientation`, etc)
- Same with `<service>`

Comment: I think from practical point of view, these do not matter. Because all manifest files will be merged together into one manifest file after project build as you can find only one AndroidManifest.xml file in each APK file. However I am not certain about its programming conventions.

Comment: If the library will be used by Android Studio, the items in the library's manifest will be merged into the overall application's manifest. I am hazy as to how much that is offered with Eclipse at the moment.